# Ex.1.7 Jech "Set Theory". (The shortest proof)

Tags: set-theory

There is an exercise on page 14 in the [Tomas Jech's "Set Theory"](https://logic.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/Jech%2C+T.+J.+%282003%29.+Set+Theory+%28The+3rd+millennium+ed.%29.pdf):

> Every nonempty $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ has an $\in$-minimal element.
>   [Pick $n \in X$ and look at $X \cap n$.]

and there is a good solution written by the user egreg: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1526646/251394 . (We deal with the intersection of all elements of the set.)

This proof has a lot of inductions. For example, we need to prove trichotomy. And induction itself is not yet proved.
That is strange because other theorems nearby (1.1-1.6 and 1.8-1.9) are very easy, relatively to 1.7.

Could you please suggest a shorter proof?

p.s. We also can use the regularity axiom, but it is not fair.

p.p.s. I think, it is sufficient to show that $\bigcap X \in X$. (Then proof by contradiction: assume $s\in X \cap \bigcap X$, so $s\in X$ and $\forall m\in X.s\in m$, which means that $s\in s$, so there is a contradiction by ex.1.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By exercise 1.6 you have that for every element $n$ of $\mathbb{N}$, if $z\subseteq n$ is not empty, then has a $\in$-minimal element. So, you have two cases

**$X\cap n=\emptyset$:** In this case $n$ is a $\in$-minimal element of $X$

$X\cap n\neq\emptyset$: As $X\cap n\subseteq n$ then exists a $\in$-minimal element $m\in X\cap n$. So, $m$ is $\in$-minimal in $X$ too.
(Edited: in the last sentence of the second case we use ex.1.4, which states that every natural number is transitive.)